# Where is the odb file?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jpa

I'm using Google App Engine with JPA, now when I am running the deployed project i can ses   the data base in DataStore Viewr.
Where can i find the odb file when i'm running in local mode?

when i worked with JPA bofore I set the direction as:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/db/profiles.odb");
```

but now when i use:

```
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
```

I don't know where to find the odb file.

Comment: WEB-INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin but tt's not in odb format (protobuf)

Comment: there is a way i can watch the content of the file?

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of Google App Engine is not based on ObjectDB, so there is no database in ObjectDB database odb file format in GAE.